# Why does this function need 'this' to be binded to it?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, es6-modules

I am following a React tutorial and I noticed that I have a function that looks like this:

```
  onDeleteClick = (id, dispatch) => {
    console.log(id);
    // this is a function which is a part of the global state
    dispatch({ type: "DELETE_CONTACT", payload: id });
  };
```

and in my form I have this:

```
<i onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind( this, this.props.id, dispatch)} className="fas fa-times" style={{ cursor: "pointer", float: "right", color: "red" }}></i>
```

So, my question is why do I need to bind 'this' to onDeleteClick because I don't use state or any other class methods inside of onDeleteClick that would require 'this'. But, when I remove it, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function`.

I see why 'this.props.id' and 'dispatch' need to be binded, but not sure why dispatch is no longer a function when I remove 'this' from this `<i>` tag.

Here is the full class:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Consumer } from "../../context";

class Contact extends Component {
  state = {
    showContactInfo: false,
    num: 1, // this is useless. just for testing things
  };

  // uses arrow function because otherwise we couldn't use 'this'
  onShowClick = (e) => {
    var newNum = this.state.num;
    newNum = newNum + 1;
    this.setState({
      showContactInfo: !this.state.showContactInfo,
      num: newNum,
    });
  };

  onDeleteClick = (id, dispatch) => {
    console.log(id);
    // this is a function which is a part of the global state
    dispatch({ type: "DELETE_CONTACT", payload: id });
  };

  render() {
    //pull boolean out of this.state
    const { showContactInfo } = this.state;
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {(value) => {
          const { dispatch } = value;
          return (
            <div className="card card-body mb-3">
              <h4>
                {this.props.name}
                <i
                  onClick={this.onShowClick}
                  className="fas fa-sort-down"
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                ></i>
                <i
                  onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(
                    this,
                    this.props.id,
                    dispatch
                  )}
                  className="fas fa-times"
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer", float: "right", color: "red" }}
                ></i>
              </h4>
              {showContactInfo ? (
                <ul className="list-group">
                  <li className="list-group-item">Email: {this.props.email}</li>
                  <li className="list-group-item">Phone: {this.props.phone}</li>
                </ul>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Consumer>
    );
  }
}

Contact.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  phone: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, when I remove it, I get the error Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function

What did you change it to when you removed it? I'm guessing this:

```
this.onDeleteClick.bind(this.props.id, dispatch)
```

If so, that's telling `.bind` that you want `this` to equal `this.props.id`, and the 0th argument (id) to be `dispatch`. The 1st argument (dispatch) will not be bound to anything.

If you like, you could set `this` equal to null or undefined:

```
this.onDeleteClick.bind(null, this.props.id, dispatch)
```

But this doesn't really gain you anything, and if you ever modify onDeleteClick to use `this` you may need to fix the binding anyway. So you might as well bind `this` to begin with.

Comment: Oh I see! So I guess my next question is, under what circumstances would I not need or want to bind 'this'? Because if you look at onShowClick, I don't bind anything to it.

Comment: If you need to use `.this` in a callback, then you'll need to do *something* to allow that to to work correctly. `.bind` is one way. Arrow functions are another (as in your onShowClick). Since both options exist, you pretty much never "need" to use `.bind`. My personal preference is to use arrow functions.

Comment: Since onShowClick and onDeleteClick both use arrow functions tho, what is the reason that I do not bind anything in onShowClick but I do in onDeleteClick? Sorry for all the questions, I have been trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I get it. onDeleteClick uses a call back 'dispatch' which is why I need to bind 'this' or else it does not see 'dispatch' as a function. So I think i need to bind 'this' everytime I pass a function as a param. is that correct?

Comment: with your onDeleteClick example, `bind` is being used to lock in the value of the function parameters (id, and dispatch). `.bind` is not the only way to do this: you could instead create a closure, as in `onClick={() => this.onDeleteClick(this.props.id, dispatch)}`. So whether we're talking the onShowClick case or the onDeleteClick case, bind is an option but not a requirement. My personal preference is to use arrow functions.

Comment: Gotcha, it all makes sense now other than I don't understand why the values need to be locked in when I have them and place the values in the parameters. Shouldn't they be passed as they are and then be accessed?

Comment: `I don't understand why the values need to be locked in` Again, both options are fine. The only thing you "need" is to somehow get the values into onDeleteClick. One way is to create a bound function, with the variables locked in. Another way is to create your own function, and pass the values in yourself. If you prefer the latter, feel free to use it. That's the way i would do it too. I don't think i've used `.bind`  in production code for about 2 years now.